# Lose BootStrap Formatting When Use Local Version

Tags: html, go, bootstrap-4

I'm writing my first web server, so don't hate.

I am using Golang and HTML with BootStrap.

This program will eventually run on a Raspberry Pi in a small device.  So I assume it would be best to use a downloaded version of BootStrap rather than the CDN version right?

But when I do this, my buttons on my page lose their formatting.

Here is my HTML code using the CDN version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Cacophonator Setup</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Cacophonator Setup</h2>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- <a href="\CameraPositioning\" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Camera Positioning</a> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='camera-positioning.html'">Camera Positioning</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='3G-connectivity.html'">3G Connectivity</button>
  </div>        
  <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='API-server.html'">API Server</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='network-interfaces.html'">Network Interfaces</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='disk-memory.html'">Disk and Memory Status</button>
  </div>

</div>

<h4>{{.Head}}<h4>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the new HTML which is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Cacophonator Setup</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Cacophonator Setup</h2>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- <a href="\CameraPositioning\" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Camera Positioning</a> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='camera-positioning.html'">Camera Positioning</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='3G-connectivity.html'">3G Connectivity</button>
  </div>        
  <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='API-server.html'">API Server</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='network-interfaces.html'">Network Interfaces</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='disk-memory.html'">Disk and Memory Status</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have only changed 2 lines, so that I use (or try to) the local BootStrap CSS and JS.

And I call it from Go like this:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", managementinterface.IndexHandler)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

And IndexHandler is like this:

```
func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("../html/index.html")
    t.Execute(w, "")

}
```

One final note: The CDN version is 3.3.7, the version I downloaded is 4.1.1

And also if I look at the local BootStrap CSS file, I can see this:

```
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #007bff;
}
```

Which is the styling I want.  Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why did you use relative URLs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ummm not sure.  Do you mean for the BootStrap files? Or the HTML files?

Comment: You have, for example, `<link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">` which is relative. You didn't put the leading `/` on it. Why not?

Comment: I really don't know Michael.  With a leading '/' it would still be a relative path wouldn't it?  But it needs to be relative doesn't it?  Can't have something like "C:\user\go\..."

Comment: With a leading `/` it is relative to the web server document root. Without the leading `/` it is relative to the path of the current URL, which is quite often not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out someone else on this open source project answered this.

What they did was pack all the static css and html pages into the Go executable.  They did this with a package called packr: https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr

It's a tool that does that for you.

So then you have only 1 file to deploy, which is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually serving the JS and CSS code from the Go code? If not, your browser is asking the Go HTTP server for the resources, but it has no idea what you're talking about (if you look at the developer console in your browser it will show you a 404 response on the requests for those files.

You may need to do something like (assuming you've got your CSS and JS in a directory called assets)

```
cssFs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/user/www/assets/css"))
http.Handle("/css", fs)
jsFs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/user/www/assets/js"))
http.Handle("/js", fs)
```

More info at [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer)

Comment: Thanks I will look into this tomorrow.  Still need to know more about this stuff even though this has been solved.